# TFS Build fails with Exec task in upgraded MSBuild build script after TFS 2012 upgrade

Tags: msbuild

We have a project where we customized the TFS build script in TFS 2008, back when the builds were MSBuild based, instead of Workflow files.  This customized script uses the [`<Exec>` task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) to call NAnt to do some packaging.

After migrating our TFS 2010 installation to a new server and upgrading to TFS 2012, that line in the TFSBuild.proj file is causing an error:

```
Target "AfterCompile: (TargetId:321)" in project "C:\Builds\2\Proj\Continuous Integration (Proj)\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj" (target "Compile" depends on it):
Using "Exec" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "Exec" (TaskId:209)
  Task Parameter:Command=C:\Tools\NAnt\bin\Nant.exe (TaskId:209)
  Task Parameter:WorkingDirectory=..\Sources\ (TaskId:209)
  Command: (TaskId:209)
  C:\Tools\NAnt\bin\Nant.exe (TaskId:209)
C:\Builds\2\Proj\Continuous Integration (Proj)\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj(225,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "cmd.exe" could not be run. The directory name is invalid
Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED. (TaskId:209)
Done building target "AfterCompile" in project "TFSBuild.proj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:321)
```

That line looks like this:

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">
  <Exec Command="C:\Tools\NAnt\bin\Nant.exe" WorkingDirectory="..\Sources\" />
  <!-- ... -->
</Target>
```

Comment: Is this with maximum verbose logging turned on? add /v:diag to the MsBuild commandline to obtain more information on what's going on.

Comment: I had forgotten to change the logging verbosity, @jessehouwing, but didn't get any additional info once I changed to diagnostic...

Comment: Strike that, I was just looking in the wrong place for the extra info (it's not in the view of the build in Visual Studio, just in the log file in the drop folder).  That said, not much more _interesting_ that it tells us.

Comment: Did you try a non relative working directory? Prepend it with $(Solution Directory) or something similar...

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the working directory, I was being blind to that part of it.  Turns out the Sources & Binaries directories were renamed in TFS 2012, and I should have been using `$(SourceSubdirectory)` instead.  If you put your comment about checking the working directory into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your working directory. I expect this to point to a non existing location.

Specifically, the default `Sources` and `Binaries` directory names were changed in TFS 2012 to `src` and `bin`.  Use the properties `$(SourcesSubdirectory)` and `$(BinariesSubdirectory)` to get the correct value.